# How to add a table into the data model (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

So inside excel they have a data model. You can access this data model in VBA, but now... It's rather easy adding a pivot table or query into the data model, but how would you add just a normal table into the data model?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?  According to the excellant [PowerPivotPro](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2014/07/adding-tables-to-a-model-from-vba-in-excel-2013/) you'll need 2013 or higher to access the data model via VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it's actually rather simple... Go to Data > Connections > Add

But click the drop down arrow on that "Add" button...

This will bring up the "Add to data model" option.

Click that, select the 2nd tab I think (Tables) and here you can add whatever table (by table name) into the data model.

Answer (score 0):

How to add a table to the data model (via VBA)

The solution is the method add2 of the Connections collection.

I recorded a macro to find this but then I found details online too: 
https://powerpivotpro.com/2014/07/adding-tables-to-a-model-from-vba-in-excel-2013/

I know this question is old, but I hope my answers helps others who got here like me.

Comment: Please make your answer useful even without a link